# Set permission for single user in Repository GIT

Tags: tfs

I need to set the security level for the GIT repository so that it is one and only domain user to have write permissions on the entered code. All others will only have read permissions. I noticed that this is possible via the Web, can you also set this option to XML file side? "VersionControl \ VersionControl.xml" - Thank you Gabriele

Answer (score 0):

If you mean set the Git permission such as [**Control access to functional areas**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/process-templates/control-access-to-functional-areas) in TFVC, it's not supported.

But for your specific requirement here, you can configure for a process template by specifying permissions in **VersionControl.xml** file, you define what actions security **groups** and **individuals** can perform on items that are under version control.

eg, set as below (Thus the **Readers** group only have the read permission, and **Contributors** group have the read and write permission) :

```
<git> 
        <permission allow="GenericRead, GenericContribute" identity="[$$PROJECTNAME$$]\Contributors" />
        <permission allow="GenericRead" identity="[$$PROJECTNAME$$]\Readers" />        
</git>
```

It will affects all the team projects and all the Git reops which are applied to the template.

I think it's not necessary, as you know we can specify the **user/Group** permission via the web conveniently to restrict the Git repo access. In different team projects we just need to add the user/Group then set the permission accordingly.